# Git - removing a commit from branch and keep progress

Tags: git, commit, revert

I know how to reset to a previous commit using git, but what is the proper way to remove a previous commit while still remaining at the current commit?

For example, I have commits w, x, y, z, but I want to remove x from the current working branch/tree/head/remote and still keep the rest of them.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Do you want to create a new commit (let's call it `a`) that undoes the changes from `w` to `x`, and end up with `w - x - y - z - a`? Or do you want to rewrite the history to pretent that `x` never existed, and end up with `w - y'- z'`?

Comment: Well, if I can keep it in the history without purging it, that would be ideal, that way I can still go in and troubleshoot the issue. This is basically just to eliminate a bug that occurred from a specific commit.

Comment: Then Nils Werner's answer is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git revert <id-of-commit>
```

This essentially creates a new commit with the "inverse diff" of `id-of-commit`. All past commits remain untouched but Git tries to undo that single one.

Also, Git *creates a new commit*. This means you can simply push the revert to your remote repositories without messing with the history.